# Create element at absolute position?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to insert an element into the DOM, essentially a floating box. completely outside the normal flow of elements, overlapping anything beneath it, *at a particular position.*

I was trying:

```
$('body').append('<div id="popup" style="width:30px; height:30px;">HEY THERE</div>');
$('#popup').position({ my: 'left top', at: 'left bottom', of: $('a').first() });
```

But wasn't getting any results. I'm trying to position the floating box directly beneath the first anchor tag in the document.

It's getting put in the DOM, but it's not being positioned right.

Possibly I should be using `insert`, or some sort of combination of relative and absolute positioning?

Comment: html if any paste it to start with..

Comment: I'm just executing this in the console at present, testing it on random pages. I'd been using this page for testing... http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2012Sep/0109.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it appended below the first anchor tag, you can try -

```
$("a").first().after('<div id="popup" style="width:30px; height:30px;">HEY THERE</div>');
```

EDIT : 
As suggested by OP :
add `position: absolute` and `z-index: 999` to place it outside.

Comment: But outside the DOM flow. Like a floating box.

Comment: what do you mean by a floating box? Could you post some fiddle link for something you've already tried?

Comment: Haha nothing I have tried so far has worked...I'm still looking for the right commands. I mean it's *on top of* any other elements...it's just floating there, outside the normal DOM. It shouldn't push anything out of the way, it should appear on top of the other elements.

Comment: Oh, I got it! `position: absolute` and `z-index: 999`! Add that into your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: USE: top:$("a").first().offset().top+$("a").outerHeight(),      left:$("a").first().offset().left+$("a").outerWidth(),

Comment: Can you...put that in an answer?? Slightly hard to read/follow :)

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at [$.offset()](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/offset/&ei=maQeUuq2O4fqiAfZrICwCg&usg=AFQjCNHh1zyFZ94eEJe1KRVgwDR9eoW_EQ&sig2=yUqJe3GvDF3UiMrBv1dSuw&bvm=bv.51495398,d.aGc):

```
var a = $('a').first(); 
var offset = a.offset(); 
var aLeft = parseInt(offset.left); 
var aTop = parseInt(offset.top); 

//And I have never used .position() I would edit the CSS: 
$("#popup").css({left: aLeft + 10, top: aTop + 10, position: "absolute", z-index: 1000});
```

Comment: Oohh I *think* that was just a transcription typo...one sec....yeah it was. Now this is great but is there a way to make it absolute RELATIVE to the first anchor tag? I suppose I could find the correct relative coordinates first manually but I was hoping to make it more concise.

Comment: This is very useful too...I'm going to keep working and probably end up combining these two answers somehow. Thanks!